# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Interpersonal Skills breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                 40         21
Users destroyed                                 150          0
Users deleted                                    13          0
Users contacted                                  74          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           186      2,096
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               74      2,113
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         83      8,376
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                8        178
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                49      3,302
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue               34      4,005
Tags merged                                       3          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             2          4
Tag synonyms created                              4          1
Questions unprotected                             7         13
Questions reopened                               28        179
Questions protected                              31        184
Questions migrated                               11          2
Questions flagged⁴                               36      1,278
Questions closed                                351      1,063
Question flags handled⁴                         785        529
Posts unlocked                                    9         10
Posts undeleted                                  65        107
Posts locked                                     19        277
Posts deleted⁵                                  765      2,565
Escalations to the CM team                       14          0
Comments undeleted                              239          0
Comments flagged                                158     13,430
Comments deleted⁶                            21,885      4,324
Comment flags handled                        11,452      2,136
Answers flagged                                 426      5,397
Answer flags handled                          1,982      3,841
All comments on a post moved to chat            106          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: What's the distinction between users destroyed and users deleted?

Comment: Destroy == troll/spammer, @apaul. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user

Comment: Happy new year to you too, Shog! Do you think we could ask you to also provide those statistics in two distinct datasets, i.e. before and after the HNQ event? It'd be nice to see the removal's impact statistically.

Comment: Hmm you report the number of community closed questions as `1,063` in the last year. Do you know why [the Data Explorer reports](https://data.stackexchange.com/interpersonal/query/edit/958370) `951` for all time?

Comment: Lots are deleted, @scohe001: https://data.stackexchange.com/interpersonal/query/958371

Comment: Huh, interesting. Guess I assumed the `PostHistory` table included histories of deleted posts. Good to know--thanks!

Comment: @avazula This doesn't answer your question directly, but I think it might still interest you and other users: https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3477/21067

Comment: These statistics specifically, @avazula? I can; post a separate request, please - if others are interested, I'll dig em out.

Comment: @Shog9 ok, thank you. I posted such a request [here](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3479/resquesting-for-2018-moderation-stats-before-and-after-hnq-removal), I'm waiting to see whether others are curious about it.